# carousel conflicts with template

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use [this template](http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/stylish-portfolio/) with a custom carousel.

I want the carousel to replace the default header, but when I put the carousel code there, nothing happens.

When I first tried it did appear, but the left and right arrows would not function properly.

Here is the carousel:

```
<header id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for Slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <!-- Set the first background image using inline CSS below. -->
            <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('');"></div>
            <div class="carousel-caption">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <!-- Set the second background image using inline CSS below. -->
            <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('');"></div>
            <div class="carousel-caption">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <!-- Set the third background image using inline CSS below. -->
            <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('');"></div>
            <div class="carousel-caption">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="icon-prev"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="icon-next"></span>
    </a>
</header>
```

And these scripts are at the bottom of the body

```
// Closes the sidebar menu
$("#menu-close").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#sidebar-wrapper").toggleClass("active");
});

// Opens the sidebar menu
$("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#sidebar-wrapper").toggleClass("active");
});

// Scrolls to the selected menu item on the page
$(function() {
    $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') || location.hostname == this.hostname) {

            var target = $(this.hash);
            target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
            if (target.length) {
                $('html,body').animate({
                    scrollTop: target.offset().top
                }, 1000);
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Please post only the relevant code in the question's body. Nobody wants to browse through your whole code. Plus, this way the code will remain available for future reference even if you remove the link's target.

Comment: Sorry!! I'm new to all this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the carousel wasn't showing up is that the carousel has to be inside the header, not the header itself. Change this

```
<header id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
...
</header>
```

To this

```
<header>
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    ...
    </div>
</header>
```

The previous and next buttons aren't working because your page has a smooth scrolling plugin. Just change this line

```
$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() { ... }
```

So that it filters out the carousel buttons, like so

```
$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#]):not([href=#myCarousel])').click(function() { ... }
```

([Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/humbleRumble/nv7rsgpg/1/))

Comment: Quick question, but I noticed on some sites if you use a really small resolution, the carousel becomes a "mini carousel" and moves to the top to preserve the width of the image. Is there anything I can change in the css to achieve this? When I removed "height: 100vh", it achieved this, but the images kept changing sizes.

Comment: They are not, so I was hoping to make it stay frozen at a certain heightxwidth.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nv7rsgpg/embedded/result/)**.

I set the fiddle up with the template and have a Bootstrap carousel fullscreen in place of the image.

The issue why you could not get it to work was because the template site uses a scroll-to in the menu links.
It was a simple fix, all that was needed was to swap the `<a href=""></a>`tags to `div`.
You could use `<button>`but this would have a shaded gray edge area in from each side.

```
 <!-- Left and right controls -->
 <div class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
 <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
 </div>
 <div class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
 <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
 </div>
```